# Why am I having index.js:1 Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm practicing with reactjs and Firebase. This is the error I can see in the console whenever I'll click the sign in button and sign in with Google button. However, I can still save it in the firebase firestore db successfully.
I'm just new with this reactjs and firebase

```
Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
    at L (index.js:1)
    at Y (index.js:1)
    at index.js:1
    at index.js:1
    at o (index.js:1)
```

Is there something wrong with the onClick button?

```
<Button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
     <Typography variant="h6" align="center" display="block">
           Sign In With Google
     </Typography>
 </Button>
```

And this is the signInWithGoogle in firebase utils:

```
const GoogleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
GoogleProvider.setCustomParameters( {prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () =>auth.signInWithPopup(GoogleProvider);
```

Comment: I guess `signInWithGoogle` doesn't return anything. So, can you try `export const signInWithGoogle = () => { auth.signInWithPopup(GoogleProvider); }`

Comment: I already did have that and it's still showing. Perhaps, is it because of my forminput?
                                <FormInput  
                                    type="email"
                                    name="email"
                                    value={email}
                                    placeholder="Email"
                                    handleChange = {this.handleChange}
                                />

Comment: Similar: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57446529/2873538

Comment: Your form input looks fine.

Comment: @AjeetShah Thank you. I'll check it out. If the problem is not fixed, will it affect the overall website?

Comment: This error doesn't seem to be a red flag. It seems minor and won't cause any harm. But we like a clean browser console so let us know when you find a fix of it :)

Comment: @AjeetShah will do, I'll try to fixed my codes a little bit with react-redux